# How to implement java Authentication in desktop application

Tags: java, authentication, desktop

what is the best way to implement AA mechanism ( authorization and Authentication ) 
in java desktop app , i have accounting application that needs AA mechanism

Comment: I am looking for some desktop applications which uses JAAS for AA. I found many sample examples but want some realistic one. So if posssible, caould you please give me ur accounting application which uses JAAS ? That would be your great help. Or could you please suggest from where can I find such applications ? It can be very small or medium size.my email id is (raginippatel@gmail.com) Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JAAS](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jaas/JAASRefGuide.html#LoginContext) can be a nice place to start.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use Kerberos for authentication. Java has built-in Kerberos client. You just need to have a KDC. If you have Windows AD, it can serve as a KDC.

You can use JAAS as the API to perform Kerberos authentication.

There is nothing built-in for authorization. I suggest you use role based authorization. You have to define the roles yourself and it can be placed inside the AuthorizationData of Kerberos ticket.

There many other authentication mechanism you can use on client. Kerberos is the only one with standard token (ticket) so users don't have to enter password over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what type of AA you have in mind.

If you want to AA against Windows Active Directory, then the easiest way is to connect to LDAP server of that directory with user's id and password (that's authentication) and read the list of groups (that's for authorization).

JAAS is rather generic and thus complex, for specific cases it's often better to use a simpler way.